# Twilio call a user, play audio and receive callback

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I need some help in achieving functionality using twilio API.
I want to call user and play some pre-recorded audio file and receive callback status/event.

Here is what I have achieved.

```
Twilio.init(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber(callDetailModel.getToNumber()),
                         new PhoneNumber(FROM_TWILIO_NUMBER),
                         new URI(API_URL + "/call/twilio/voice/demo-voice")).create();
```

Now in "/call/twilio/voice/demo-voice" I am generating TwiML.

```
Play play = new Play.Builder(
                "demo-play.wav")
                .loop(1).build();

Number number = new Number.Builder(request.getParameter("Caller"))
                .statusCallback(API_URL + "/call/twilio/events-demo")
                .statusCallbackMethod(Method.POST).statusCallbackEvents(Arrays
                .asList(Event.INITIATED, Event.RINGING, Event.ANSWERED, Event.COMPLETED)).build();
Dial dial = new Dial.Builder()
                .timeLimit(60)
                .callerId(request.getParameter("Called"))
                .record(Dial.Record.DO_NOT_RECORD)
                .number(number).build();
VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).play(play).build();
return (twiml.toXml());
```

And now in event callback we are checking if receiver has received call or not, is it completed or not etc.

Now, the problem is when user receive a call auto voice mail of Twilio is getting played and after that my **demo-play.wav** get played. We want to remove that twilio voice mail and want to play only **demo-play.wav** which we have passed through TwiML.

**UPDATE:**

The audio getting played is here.
https://vocaroo.com/i/s0KNEhHxUKX5

Also the twiml which is generated is something like this

```
<Response>
    <Dial timeLimit="7200" callerId="+1xxxxx" record="record-from-answer-dual">
        <Number statusCallbackEvent="initiated ringing answered completed" statusCallback="http://38c5cb01.ngrok.io/call/twilio/events-demo" statusCallbackMethod="POST">+1zzzzzzzz</Number>
    </Dial>
    <Play loop="1">https://aws.xxx.H1OAOec30bbc5-bc3a-4251-a27c-2e4e41b386061521208641292FOIZ1.wav</Play>
</Response>
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to pass the `Play` in `Dial` verb? If then how?

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a trial account.  Trial accounts inject a message at the start of a call.  If you upgrade that goes away.

Comment: @DevinRader thanks for the prompt response. I think its not because the trial account. I have updated my question with audio url which is playing initially. And also posted the TwiML. can you please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: So you just want to get call status events on the initial outbound call?  Then you don't need the <Dial> in your TwiML.  You just need to specify the status callback URL in the Call.creator method.  See this sample code: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-make-a-call-and-monitor-progress-events&code-language=java&code-sdk-version=7.x